# Who are the 33 koti devas ? Does the word 'koti' mean type(category) or crore (number)?

Tags: gods

(Other similar questions on this site don't have proper answer with scriptural reference. The [Wikipedia answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty-three_gods) doesn't cite sources, also don't think it's accurate, because Gita 'rudranam sankaras casmi', and sankar is not mentioned in that site)

We say there are 33 koti devas, but the word 'crore' is said to be a bad-translation of the word 'koti', which apparently means 'type', although I didn't find that [definition](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&script=hk&tran_input=koti) in spokensanskrit.org

Any case, the 33 devas are said to be :

8 vasu + 12 aditya + 11 rudra + 2 ashvini = 33

What are the names of the 33 devas and what are the duties of their posts in universe ?